# SSRS Report Viewer API - field expression returns empty for MDX data source

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2019

I'm using the SSRS ReportViewer control to display a local RDL report with a shared data source pointing to an SSAS cube.

I'm using the `Microsoft.Reporting.Webforms` API to add the MDX DataSource to the `LocalReport` object. The DataSource queries fine and I assign it to the report object, something like this:

```
        var adapter = new AdomdDataAdapter();
        var queryCmd = connection.CreateCommand();

        adapter.SelectCommand = queryCmd;
        RdlQuery rdlQuery = rdlDataSet.Query;
        queryCmd.CommandText = rdlQuery.CommandText;

        var adoNetDataSet = new DataSet();

        using (connection)
        {
            connection.Open();
            var schemaDs = new DataSet();
            adapter.FillSchema(schemaDs, SchemaType.Source);

            var mapping = new DataTableMapping
            {
                DataSetTable = "Table",
                SourceTable = schemaDs.Tables[0].TableName
            };

            foreach (RdlField field in rdlDataSet.Fields)
                mapping.ColumnMappings.Add(field.DataField, field.Name);

            adapter.TableMappings.Add(mapping);
            adapter.Fill(adoNetDataSet);
        }

        var reportDs = new rs.ReportDataSource(rdlDataSet.Name, adoNetDataSet.Tables[0]);
        localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDs);
```

**Result:**

When I run it returns empty in the Report Viewer control. The same query works fine in the Visual Studio report designer preview.

**Additional Information:**

In the Report:
The DataSet queries the cube like so:

```
SELECT [Measures].[CurrentAmount] as CurrentAmount ON COLUMNS,
    STRTOMEMBER("[Year].[version].[" + @Param1 + "]") ON ROWS
FROM [Model]
```

And has the field:

```
Name: CurrentAmount
Field Source: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Field xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Measure" UniqueName="[Measures].[CurrentAmount]" />
```

I am using the following Field Expression to display the data:

```
=First(Fields!CurrentAmount.Value, "DataSet1")
```

I think it might have to do with the column mappings... I have tried debugging the DataTable I can see the column name is set to [Measures].[CurrentAmount] which is different than the Field Expression `CurrentAmount`. I tried changing it while debugging to just `CurrentAmount` so far this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the Field Source from the automatically generated xml to the Member by itself it works in the SSRS report viewer. The same does not work in the Visual Studio Preview.

```
Name: CurrentAmount
Field Source: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Field xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Measure" UniqueName="[Measures].[CurrentAmount]" />
```

to

```
Name: CurrentAmount  
Field Source: CurrentAmount
```